# Grid view Delete Update on single click

Tags: c#, sql-server

My problem is I have a delete button in grid view. if i click on delete button that particular row need to be deleted and some columns of that row need to be updated which on same button click.

example if i click delete that row that row needs to be deleted..that row has Status column which is active before deleting, after clicking delete that column status should change to delete, and row should be deleted and one more column that id should change to null.

very confused how to do both operations on single click

Comment: if you are deleting the row, then why you'veto update the columns of the same row??? your question is so confusing. Let us know what you've tried.

Comment: Are you looking for something like "Soft Delete" wherein, if you click on "Delete", the status of the row is updated to something like "Inactive" and the row; though still present in database, will not be displayed in grid??

Comment: row column will change to inactive. and that row wil be updated in database and grid also

Comment: @DirtyDeveloper I have edited my question, what i have tried

Comment: @Jones what problem you're facing. what new you need?

Answer (score 0):

You should do all of operations like update/delete on **DataSource** assigned to DataGrid. For your convenience

```
private void PopulateThirdCombo()
{
    try
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.Add("Product ID");
        dt.Columns.Add("Product Name");
        dt.Columns.Add("Product Price");
        dt.Columns.Add();
        dataGridView1.ColumnCount = 3;
        dataGridView1.Columns[0].Name = "Product ID";
        dataGridView1.Columns[1].Name = "Product Name";
        dataGridView1.Columns[2].Name = "Product Price";
        string[] row = new string[] { "1", "Product 1", "1000" };
        dataGridView1.Rows.Add(row);
        row = new string[] { "2", "Product 2", "2000" };
        dataGridView1.Rows.Add(row);
        row = new string[] { "3", "Product 3", "3000" };
        dataGridView1.Rows.Add(row);
        row = new string[] { "4", "Product 4", "4000" };
        dataGridView1.Rows.Add(row);

        DataGridViewButtonColumn btn = new DataGridViewButtonColumn();
        dataGridView1.Columns.Add(btn);
        btn.HeaderText = "Action";
        btn.Text = "Delete";
        btn.Name = "btn";
        btn.UseColumnTextForButtonValue = true;     
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {

    }
}


private void dataGridView1_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        //this will be index of your delete button
        if (e.ColumnIndex == 3)
        {
            this.dataGridView1.Rows.RemoveAt(e.RowIndex);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {

    }
}
```

**NOTE:** Call PopulateThirdCombo() first